# Big O of nested for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, big-o, nested-loops

```
int y = 1;
for (int x = 1 ; x <= n+2 ; x++)
  for (int w = n ; w > 0 ; w--)
    y = y + 1;
```

I'm a little confused about determining the BigO of the above code. If in the outermost loop it was for(int x = 1; x <= n; w++), then the BigO of the loop would be O(n^2) because the outermost loop would iterate n times and the innermost loop would also iterate n times.

However, given that the outermost loop iterates n+2 times, would that change the bigO or does the rule that additive constants don't matter imply? Lastly, would it change anything if the innermost loop were to iterate n+2 times instead of n?

Thank you!

Comment: As `n` goes to infinity, a `+2` swiftly becomes irrelevant. You're taking the limit of `(n+2)*(n)`, which equals `n^2 + 2n`, as `n` goes to infinity.

Answer (score 3):

Outer loop run `n + 2` times, and inner loop runs `n` times, so code block runs `(n + 2) * n` times, which is `n * n + 2 * n` times. With increasing values of `n`, the `2 * n` becomes insignificant, so you're left with `n * n`, giving you the answer: **O(n^2)**

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int x = 1 ; x <= n+2 ; x++)
```

outer loop is (n+2) times.

```
  for (int w = n ; w > 0 ; w--)
```

inner loop is (n) time

`((n+2) * n)` => `n^2 + 2n` => `O(n^2)`. Because we consider the larger value.

> The reason is for the larger values of `n`, value of `2n` will be insignificant to `n^2`. So we drop the `n`.

You can read here for more explanation: [Big O Analysis](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/data-structures/big-o-notation/)

Comment: Does the 2 in (n+2) drop then during the multiplication of ((n+2)*n)) because of the additive constants don't matter rule?

Comment: @MikeNeal it drop because it is smaller than the n^2. Only consider what is the maximum.

Comment: @MikeNeal when you consider the larger values then 2n will be way smaller then n^2. so it does not affect much of the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Long-ish answer short, the additive constants don't matter.

Suppose we did count the constants.  Then, the inner loop is executed

```
(n+2)(n) = n^2 + 2n
```

times.  This is still `O(n^2)`, since the squared term takes precedence over the linear term.

Answer (score 1):

n and n+2 are the same order of magnitude, so this code run in O(n^2).
Even if the inner loop runs n + 2 times.